# JQuery UI Selecting between specific Months in year datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am new with JQuery and I wanted to see if I could do something like this using JQuery UI datepicker.

I want to show from January 1 through March 30 of every year OR a specific year .. and disable other dates. The first picked date should be 5 business days from today.

Is it possible. I did see some range etc on JQuery UI but I did not quite understand.

Thanks

**Update**

I could do something like below able to get the users to select only 5 days from today.

```
minDate: +5, maxDate: "+3M +10D",
```

**Update**

```
                      showButtonPanel: true,
                      minDate: new Date(2012, 1, 2),
                      maxDate: new Date(2012, 3,30),
                      minDate: + 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the min and max date.

**HTML**

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

<p>New Date: <input type="text" id="test"></p>

</div>
```

**JavaScript (two different examples. First hard set dates. The second gets the current day + 5 days.**

```
  $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
           minDate: new Date(2012, 0, 1),
           maxDate: new Date(2012, 2, 31)}
        );

        var today= new Date();
        var numberofDays = 5;
        var newDate = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()+numberofDays);
        $( "#test" ).datepicker({
           minDate: newDate,
           maxDate: 5}//number of days from the start date
        );
    });
```

Here are some examples with jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rpNXZ/1/

​

​

Comment: Thank you so much, I modified your answer and came up with above I added to Update.